# Can't update ClickOnce from a different location

Tags: .net, clickonce

My install location for my .NET application is for "CD, DVD, or USB drive".
The user will receive a .zip of the .application, setup.exe and the Application Files folder.

When the user installs it by just .application, it works fine.
If the user then gets a new .zip with a newer version and they try to run the .application in a different location from where they initially installed, they get this error:
`"You cannot start application xxx from this location because it is already installed from a different location."`.
That's because the user is trying to install the application in path Y when it was initially installed in X.

Is there a way to make ClickOnce simply ignore this requirement? I can't assume the user keeps that initial path, and I want to be able to allow them to update from any location.

The product name, suite and whatnot stay the same - just the version and the actual application compiled files for the new versions.

Existing answers do not answer this (old). [This is the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5468987), however, it's old and does not apply to me. I am not doing anything online.